# MockEJB - JUnit Mockito - cannot rebind a mock EJB on second unit test

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, ejb, mockito

Hi I have a question related to MockEJB. I need to write unit tests to test a code that is calling a EJB. I use Mockito to write a mock for the EJB, and MockEJB to simulate the JNDI context.

My tests look like this :

```
 @Test
 public void test1() throws Exception {
  // create a mock instance
  NetworkManager aMockManager = createMockNetworkManager();
  // deploy it in mock container and register it in JNDI
  registerMockNetworkManager(aMockManager);

  // encapsulates the JNDI lookup
  NetworkManager manager = NetworkManagerAccessor.getNetworkManager();
  // call a method
  manager.deleteObject(new TopicId(-1), null, this.userContext);
  // verify that the method was called on the mock
  verify(aMockManager).deleteObject(new TopicId(-1), null, this.userContext);
 }

 @Test
 public void test2() throws Exception {
  // create a mock instance
  NetworkManager aMockManager = createMockNetworkManager();
  // deploy it in mock container and register it in JNDI
  registerMockNetworkManager(aMockManager);

  // encapsulates the JNDI lookup
  NetworkManager manager = NetworkManagerAccessor.getNetworkManager();
  // call a method
  manager.deleteDataItem(new DataItemId(-1), null, null, null);

  // verify that the method was called on the mock
  verify(aMockManager).deleteDataItem(new DataItemId(-1), null, null, null);
 }
```

The first test runs fine, however the second test systematically fails (mockito says the expected method was not called) While debugging, I can see that the second time I attempt to deploy the mock EJB to the JNDI, it is *not* deployed, and the first mock object is still there. **So in fact the second test is fecthing from the JNDI the mock created in the first test.**
Note also that if I run the second test alone (by commenting the first one), it runs fine.

My setup and clean method look like this :

```
 @Before
 public void setupMockJNDI() {
  try {

   // setup mockEJB
   MockContextFactory.setAsInitial();
   Context jndiContext = new InitialContext();

   // create the mock container
   mockContainer = new MockContainer( jndiContext );
  } catch (NamingException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
  }

 }

 @After
 public void unregisterJNDI() {
  // reset mock context
  MockContextFactory.revertSetAsInitial();
 }
```

I really don't understand what happens, my tests look very similar to the mock EJB examples. Does anyone have an idea ?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried to reset the JNDI context?

Comment: Hi Thanks for stopping by ! I am still struggling on this. What do you mean by reseting the JNDI context ? I tried to set it to null before each test, but it did not changed anything. Did you had something else in mind ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes I found the answer... just yesterday ! In fact it is not related to MockEJB, but to my code, that is doing JNDI lookup cache. This call :

```
NetworkManager manager = NetworkManagerAccessor.getNetworkManager();
```

Encpasulates the JNDI lookup like this :

```
NetworkManagerHome home = (NetworkManagerHome)ServiceLocator.getInstance().getService(NetworkManagerHome.JNDI_NAME, NetworkManagerHome.class);
```

And the ServiceLocator is **statically** caching its JNDI lookups, and also JNDI context :

```
public Object getService(String jndiName, Class className) {        
    Object narrowedService = null;
    if (cache.containsKey(jndiName)) {
        narrowedService = cache.get(jndiName);
    } else {
        // see J2EE design patterns page 197
        synchronized(this) {
            try {
                Object service = ctx.lookup(jndiName);
                narrowedService = PortableRemoteObject.narrow(service, className);
            } catch (NamingException ne) {
                throw new ServiceLocatorException("Cannot find service : "+jndiName, ne);
            }
            cache.put(jndiName, narrowedService);
        }
    }
    return narrowedService;
}
```

So the solution consisted in reseting this cache before each test :

```
Context jndiContext = new InitialContext();
ServiceLocator.getInstance().reset(jndiContext);

// in ServiceLocator :
public void reset(Context c) {
    this.cache = new Hashtable<String, Object>();
    this.ctx = c;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In these cases I find it easier to create the mock outside the tests and reuse it:

```
private static ServiceToMock serviceMock = mock(ServiceToMock.class);

@BeforeClass
public static void injectServiceSomewhere(){
    //...
}
@Before
public void resetServiceMock() {
    reset(serviceMock);
}
```

That should do it.